# Recommended RDF IDE/Editor?

Tags: editor, rdf

I've done a bit of searching around for a good RDF editor. But I'm not sure what one is the most utilised. Can anyone recommend one? I'm looking to write some simple RDF and maybe parse one or two RDF documents.

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you looking to work at the raw Triples level and in a human readable/editable syntax such as Turtle?  If so you can get by just with Notepad or maybe try out my [rdfEditor](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/content.asp?pageID=rdfEditor) which is an early Alpha release but gives you nice syntax highlighting, checking and auto-completion.  This is designed only for editing raw RDF data and does not give you any IDE tools for creating your data.

If you want to work at the class/individual (i.e. more abstract level) and have the editor care about the underlying RDF then you probably want to try either [TopBraid Composer](http://www.topbraidcomposer.com) or [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/overview/protege-owl.html)

Comment: Yes currently it only runs on Windows because it relies on WPF which has not been ported to Mono and so can't run on other OSes

Comment: rdfEditor appears (not comprehensively tested) to be working with the current development version of wine https://www.winehq.org/

Comment: I had some issues with rdfEditor, so I switched back to Notepad++ with [RDF extension](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/notepadpp_turtle.xml)

Answer (score 3):

There's a new TextMate bundle for the Turtle RDF language which offers a bunch of cool features. https://github.com/peta/turtle.tmbundle

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the screenshots, **Rhodonite** http://rhodonite.angelite.nl/ makes a good impression. 
Unfortunately it seems to be abandonded and I could not get it to run on Windows7 (x64). But maybe it runs on your system (download is Windows only)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a web-based RDF / Ontology editor, have a look at [Web Protege](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/WebProtege), an open source web-based project by the Protege team mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more advanced RDF editor, look at [RDF and SPARQL plugin](https://rdfandsparql.com/) for JetBrains IDEs. It supports all RDF 1.1 formats as well as SPARQL 1.1. Including the RDF-star and SPARQL-star extensions.

It features syntax highlighting and validation, prefixed name completion, SPARQL 1.1 Protocol support and much more.

You don't have to buy a JetBrains IDE, since the plugin works with the free versions too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a GUI editor,
then an option is [MR³](https://mrcube.org/).

It is written in Java and works on multiple operating systems (tested brifly on Linux).

Main interface is for  modelling RDF and RDFS objects, and a source editor can be loaded to edit directly as Turtle or other formats.